# How to conditionally normalize values in a RDD Column in PySpark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, max, normalization

**what I want to do :**

Transform the **input df1** into the desired **output df2**.
I am trying to **normalize values** in a column within a Spark DataFrame using python, *when the value of a row is above a certain threshold only*.

---

**What I have (df1) :**

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([ ('A',50,80),
                         ('B',110,90),
                         ('C',150,130),
                         ('D',230,280)
                       ], ["item","X","Y"])
```

**What I want (df2) :**

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([ ('A',50,80),
                         ('B',107.7,90),
                         ('C',138.5,116.7),
                         ('D',200,200)
                       ], ["item","X","Y"])
```

---

**What I managed so far :**

while using the following normalization logic :

```
for Xi > 100
Wi = ( Xi - Min_X) / (Max_X - Min_X) * 100 + Min_X
where Min_X = 100 and Max_X = Max(X) (in that case 230)
else Wi = Xi
```

and

```
for Yi > 100
Zi = ( Xi - Min_Y) / (Max_Y - Min_Y) * 100 + Min_Y
where Min_Y = 100 and Max_Y = Max(Y) (in that case 280)
else Zi = Yi
```

*that is, the normalization should be distinct for each columns (as the Max might differ from column to column)*

I tried to use following code, but I face a conflict in structure type.

```
Min_X = 100
Max_X = df.select(max(df.X)).alias('max').collect()
df = df.withColumn("X", when(col("X")>100, F.round((col("X") - Min_X)/(Max_X - Min_X),2)).otherwise(col("X")))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

---

**notes :**

- the result can either replace the current value in the given column
  or be populated in a new column.
- if possible, the solution should
  work for 1 or N columns
- for performance reason and if possible, solution should stick to
  pyspark library.

---

*Thank you very in advance for your time and feedback !*

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is because Min_X is Int and Max_X is of type Row.

Try this

```
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame([ ('A',50,80), ('B',110,90), ('C',150,130), ('D',230,280)], ["item","X","Y"])
>>> df1.show()
+----+---+---+
|item|  X|  Y|
+----+---+---+
|   A| 50| 80|
|   B|110| 90|
|   C|150|130|
|   D|230|280|
+----+---+---+

>>> Min_X = 100
>>> Max_X = df1.select(max(df1.X)).alias('max').collect()
>>> Max_X
[Row(max(X)=230)]
>>> Max_X = Max_X[0][0]
>>> Max_X
230
>>> df = df1.withColumn("X", when(col("X")>100, round((col("X") - Min_X)/(Max_X - Min_X),2)).otherwise(col("X")))
>>> df.show()
+----+----+---+
|item|   X|  Y|
+----+----+---+
|   A|50.0| 80|
|   B|0.08| 90|
|   C|0.38|130|
|   D| 1.0|280|
+----+----+---+
```

Comment: thank you @Hegde . Amending the code with [0][0] did the trick.

I wrote it as such :
>> Max_X = df1.select(max(df1.X)).alias('max').collect()[0][0]

and then corrected the normalization this way :
>> df2 = df1.withColumn("X", when(col("X")>100, \
round((col("X") - Min_X)/(Max_X - Min_X)*100+Min_X,2)) \
.otherwise(col("X")))